# An example showing shared lock is not compatible with the Exclusive lock

Tags: sql-server, database, locking

Bring an example showing shared lock is not compatible with the Exclusive lock.(preferably in Adventure works 2012)

Comment: Can you expand on your question.  It is not clear what you are asking?

Comment: Homework or course assignment? How far have you gone? If you're not even going to attempt, I don't think you'll get much help here.